# Windows are not showing when using cmd+tab

Tags: macos

On some occasions, when I use cmd+tab to switch to a window, the window itself doesnt show- though the menu bar of that window does show.
If I want to show the window, I have to the doc and click the icon- and then the window will show.

I thought it has to do with the desktop space of that window, but it isnt- I just can't seem to make the window show on cmd+tab, I have to click it from the doc.

Am I missing something? is there a way to show the window when using cmd+tab?

Comment: AFAIK it's a bug in Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to add post as comment but i don't have the privilege

When does this happen to you?
if it happens in Parallels Desktop Coherence mode, try Alt+Tab