# Cmd-Tab loses Focus after recent update

Tags: macbook-pro

**Model:** MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2018, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports)

Cmd-Tab to an application does not keep focus on the app. I have to click on the application for it to get focussed on.

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: Does it happen with all applications or only with specific ones?

Comment: This happens with all applications

Comment: Which version of macOS are you running? Can you create a new user acccount on your Mac and check whether it happens there as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows are not showing when using cmd+tab](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111675/windows-are-not-showing-when-using-cmdtab)

Comment: Do you use an external display or does the problem occur with the built-in monitor?

Comment: @glorfindel
The suggested post does not answer my question. The suggested posted talks about the windows not showing. In my case, it switches to the right window, but the focus is not on the window - I need to click on it to get it in focus.

Comment: @jaume I see this happening with both of my macs. 1 is connected to external displays and the other isn't.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You write " it switches to the right window, but the focus is not on the window". Could you post a screenshot of such a window after pressing Command-Tab (press Shift+Command+3 and crop the file saved to the Desktop to the relevant window)? Which is the active app according to the menu bar in the top of the display (I mean, let's say you switch to Mali, but the main Mail window doesn't get focus, which is the active app as shown in the menu bar)?